# Copying files from a path using Python

Tags: python, pandas, file, directory, subdirectory

I am new to the world of python. Have managed to do most of the data checks, but stuck on one issue.

I have got a list with filenames on a column in a dataframe, more than 150k file names. I need to look into folders and sub folders on a given path using python for the files in the list. If found, copy the file into another folder. I also need mark that we have found the file on the orginal dataframe by creating a column and adding an yes or 1 for each of the files found.

Can you guys please help.

Comment: In SO you need to post a code you tried before asking the question

Comment: It would be better if you could show the code and some sample data. Also, you could take a look at the ```apply``` function in pandas.